# Disable single test in Play 2.4 scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.4

I have some long running tests in my project. These these are sitting in parallel to my integration and unit-tests in

```
/test/manual/*
```

Is there in Play 2.4 for Scala a way to disable/mark these test classes. So they are not run automaticly when

```
$ activator test
```

but only run when using the test-only command.

Problem is that I do not want to run these longer tests on my CI server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having similar problems for long-running integration tests, I created an `It` configuration derived from the standard test config (in `<projectHome>/build.sbt`):

```
lazy val It = config("it").extend(Test)
```

Then I add the sources and test sources to this config

```
scalaSource in It <<= (scalaSource in Test)
```

and you needd to enable to config and corresponding tasks available in the current project

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).configs(It)
                                      .settings(inConfig(It)(Defaults.testTasks): _*)
```

I then disable long running  tests in the `Test` config :

```
testOptions in Test := Seq(Tests.Argument("exclude", "LongRunning"))
```

And include only these long running tests in the `It` config:

```
testOptions in It := Seq(Tests.Argument("include", "LongRunning"))
```

These last 2 configs are kinda dependent on the test framework you use (specs2 in my case, scala test would probably use [`-n` and `-l`](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_runner#filtering) in addition to [tags](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/tagging_your_tests)   to achieve the same)

Then `sbt test` will exclude all LongRunning tests and you can run `it:test` or `it:testOnly your.long.running.TestCaseHere` in an interactive sbt session if need be.

Comment: Okay - that was also the only way I saw to solve this problem, hoped/thought there was a simpler solution, maybe a simple annotation. But thanks.